# How can I reduce the font size of an algorithm?

Tags: fonts, algorithms

I want to reduce the font size of my algorithm in this code:

```
\begin{small}
\medskip
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= loop main]

 for (double x = 1 + 1; x <= 2 - 1; x++) {
 }
 
\end{lstlisting}
{\small source: unknown \dots\par\medskip}  % <--- defined "in-line"
\end{small}
```

What I tried has not worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can decrease the font size (as well as set fontface and other font characteristics) through the parameter `basicstyle` in `lstlisting` environment:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=Java,escapechar=|,caption= loop main,basicstyle=\scriptsize]
    
    for (double x = 1 + 1; x <= 2 - 1; x++) {
    }
    
\end{lstlisting}
```

Or you can set the font sizes globally in `\lstset{}` command, for example:

```
\lstset{
   basicstyle=\scriptsize,
   commentstyle=\scriptsize\sl,
   escapechar=|
}
```